# setter and getter method not recognized

Tags: java, struts2

I'm strut2 beginner and I'm testing my very first example of hello world. Here is my action class:

```
package com.tutorialspoint.struts2;

public class HelloWorldAction {
    private String myname  = "";

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Execute successfully");
        return "success";
    }

    public String getMyname() {
        return this.myname;
    }

    public void setMyname(String name) {
        System.out.println("myName is set");
        this.myname = name;
    }
}
```

Here is the first page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World From Struts2</h1>
   <form action="hello">
      <label for="myName">Please enter your name</label><br/>
      <input type="text" name="myname" value="No name"/>
      <input type="submit"/>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the second page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hello World, <s:property value="myname"/>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally the configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
   <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">

      <action name="hello" 
            class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.HelloWorldAction" 
            method="execute">
            <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
      </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

The problem is when I press the button with my entered name, it shows the error:

```
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor error
Unexpected Exception caught setting 'myname' on 'class com.tutorialspoint.struts2.HelloWorldAction: Error setting expression 'myname' with value ['No name', ]
```

If I changed property 'myname' to 'name' in action class and also the corresponding jsp files, it runs well without errors.
Please suggest a fix.

Comment: It shows the same error

Answer (score 1):

just check your jar files . 
i just copy paste you code in my project and it is running fine without any error

Comment: Not really an answer, more like a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the naming convention of camelCase in variables in your POJO class. I find Struts2 very sensitive towards it .

I faced one issue : If you name a variable eMail then struts will not work for this.If rename it to elecMail then it will work .

See the pattern : eMail will have setter and getter method as  setEMail() and getEMail() i.e. two consecutive capital letters . Struts may have some defect in finding setter method name .

May be something similar you are facing.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I've thought that until I restart tomcat server. Actually the issue comes from not restarting the server. I'm the beginner and I think I've learned something.

Comment: S2 is NOT camel case convention sensitive. The case with single first lower char is due to how accessors are being generated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the cause of the issue. After changing property name, method's names and jsp files, we have to restart the server. Only refreshing the browser causes the problem. Extending ActionSuppport or not doesn't affect relate to the issue.